# Ionic App aborting request with response status -1

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

> I'm using Ionic platform for my mobile application. Using angular
>   **$http** for sending requests to server.
>
> **Intermittently** when Mobile app tries to access server $http goes to it's **errorCallback** with response **status -1 only** no other
>   data.
>
> When I check log on server, not able to see any hit.
>
> I've changed timeout of application to 2 minutes using interceptors.
>
> I have used chrome debugger but it won't show anything apart from
>   request it forms, shows nothing in response and preview columns.
>
> I got that in Ionic we use pre-flight to check if server is alive
>   before sending actual request. But it's for CORS; we **have enabled
>   CORS** on server and thats why app is working good since last 15 days.
>
> Thought of using network packet tracer tool but if call not logged on
>   server no use of it. as **Status -1 says $http aborted the request**.
>   My Question is **why it's aborting** when I click once and do send
>   when I click same button again.
>
> Please me help to figure out an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging and surfing over internet for issue.
I guess that an issue was like mobile app sending pre-flight messages and so $http aborting the request and even some time Server played a culprit here how will tell you;
We have server hosted on AWS in where we had Load balancer in different zone and actual API server is in different zone. After changing them to same zone ask, production people to test now they are not getting this issue.

The another reason was we were using unstable mobile networks to test.

If any one have any thing else on this please let me know.